# Magento -Adding multiple Shipping method

Tags: magento

How to add **3 Flat rate shipping methods** . i want to add Standard,2nd day Air,Next Day Air Shipping methods.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add new shipping methods for this I think.

There are some tutorials about this. See for example: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/28617/ and mainly this (tutorial): http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. but i tried first link. its not working. 3 shipping methods are coming. after selected shipping method Order Review part its goes and message is showing "Shipping method is not Selected yet"

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand were you are stuck. Did you create the shipping methods according to the tutorial? And are you able to select them at the checkout?

Comment: According tutorial  i can create shipping method and i can select also. but when at the time of place order ,selected shipping method is going and Message is appearing

Comment: Shipping Method | Change Flaterate - Standard $4.99

Comment: After Selected Shipping Method | Change Flaterate - Standard $4.99     After Selected Payment option                                                            Shipping Method | Change
    "Shipping method has not been selected yet  " message appears

Comment: solved through http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2011/06/09/creating-a-custom-magento-shipping-method/

Answer (score 1):

If you need such shipping methods available on checkout page use one of already created extension. For example:

First: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Yarhajile/extension/728/multiple-tablerates

Second: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/IDEALIAGroup/extension/3224/ig-multi-flat-shipping

Comment: these extensions  are not supporting our magento. Magento Enterprise 1.9 is using.

Comment: Are you try to install this extensions? Usually developer don't have possibility to test on Enterprise version but almost of time it's working well. In any case, it would be good point to start develop your required shippings methods.

Comment: solved through http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2011/06/09/creating-a-custom-magento-shipping-method/