# Either Table Rates or Shopping Cart Rule should be used for "free shipping based on zip code" to work with all methods

Tags: magento-1.5, magento, magento-1.6

I want to give free shipping for certain regions with specified zip codes. How will i achieve this functionality ?

I have two options of "Table Rates" and "Shopping Cart Rule". Now which one will work for me in all shipping methods such USPS and Fedex etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution and it worked very fine. And the solution was to use shopping cart rule cery well defined on this link

http://addoa.com/blog/how-restrict-free-shipping-magento

Answer (score 0):

You should buy an extension for that. There are plenty of custom-rate ones. We use a custom rate extension that allows us to write in the shipping via the admin interface.

Also see [Magento -Adding multiple Shipping method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978178/magento-adding-multiple-shipping-method)